# 'SUB' in T-SQL JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to update a query for a client to add more functionality on a MS-SQL Server 2014 database. The query was written by someone else, and is currently working.

The `FROM` part of the query contains the following:

```
 FROM Project Phs
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Stage WHERE Status >=5 ) SUB 
            ON pmsProject = phs.prjPhase
        LEFT JOIN InvoiceGroup ON phs.prjInvoiceGroup = igKey
        LEFT JOIN Vec  ON vecKey = igClient
        LEFT JOIN Project Prj ON Prj.prjkey = Phs.prjproject
        LEFT JOIN Contact ON prj.prjClientContact1 = cntkey
        LEFT JOIN Project L2 ON L2.prjkey = phs.prjPhaseLevel2
```

What does `SUB` on line 2 do here?

I can't find `SUB` in the `JOIN` documentation, `SUB` is not a reserved word in T-SQL, and `SUB` does not appear anywhere else in the (300 line) query. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub is nothing more than a table alias from which the columns from the stage table can be referenced.

The join could be written as `sub.pmsProject=phs.prjphase`.

It's similar to phs for project and prj for project.

All fields from the stage table can be refereed to as sub.fieldname.  This is necessary when tables have fields with the same name so the engine knows specifically what table you want to access data from.

Aliases not only make it easier to code, it makes the code easier to read instead of having long drawn out table names.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply an alias for the `(SELECT * FROM Stage WHERE Status >=5 )` subquery so that it can be referenced later. I do not see it referenced anywhere else in the query you have provided, but you may have trimmed off a portion that contains it, or it may have been removed previously.